# suppress variable expansion in awk command

Tags: shell, awk

I want to get some specific lines from a file `a.txt`, code goes like this:

```
cat a.txt | awk '{if($0 > 100) print}'
```

and it works fine.

BUT, for some reason, I have to put the above command into a variable like this:

```
cmd="cat a.txt | awk '{if($0 > 100) print}'"
```

and I got a problem made `$0`, because it'll expand to the first parameter of the script, far from what it actually should be.

How could I resolve it?

Comment: Rather than `cat a.txt | awk ...`, just do `awk '$0 > 100' a.txt`

Comment: Why do you want the command in a string?  It just makes life very difficult, as you've just demonstrated.

Comment: There is a bug in some part of the script you aren't showing us. Most likely a mismatched single quote character so the opening quote on the awk command is being treated as the closing quote from that earlier unmatched quote.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, absolutely I knew that I it should be like `awk '$0 >100' a.txt`, I just improvised the stupid code to illustrate what my problem resembles.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the truth is I should put that command in a `hadoop` job's `mapper`, like `-mapper "*** | awk '{if($0 > 100) print}'"` , see?

Comment: @EdMorton, the reason why I do it

Comment: @Alcott you stand a much better chance of getting an actual answer if you show us your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add backslashes before the `$` until it works.

Comment: Rather than adding backslashes "until it works", it might be a good idea to think about why the backslashes are necessary.  If the string contains multiple special characters, exhausting over the permutations of added escape characters will be tedious and fragile!

Comment: No!!! This is absolutely the wrong thing to do. There is a bug elsewhere in your script that's causing the behavior you're seeing at this line and sticking random characters in various locations to try to get the error message to go away is absolutely going to come back and bite you down the road.